# Cant query images table using entity framework and ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to query my post table to display in the front-end via ajax.

This is my query:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetGalleryLocations()
{
    var data = _context.Posts
       .Include(c => c.Category)
       .ToList();

    return Json(data);
}
```

Then in my front-end, I get it like this:

```html
 $.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("GetGalleryLocations", "Home")",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
          title: '',
          lat: '',
          lng: '',
          images: []
      },
      success: function (data) {
          data.forEach(function (element) {
              $("#ajaxAppendDIV").append(
                 // Append HTML here
              );
          });
      }      
});
```

This is what I get back in response:
[image]

Each post has many images related to it, so I need to do a query like this;

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetGalleryLocations()
{
    var data = _context.Posts
       .Include(c => c.Category)       
       .Include(c => c.Images) 
       .ToList();

    return Json(data);
}
```

But when I preform this query, I get back:
[image]

Here is my relationship between two models:
Post model

```
 public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }     
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double Lat { get; set; }
        public double Lng { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }

        // .....
    }
```

Images Model:

```
 public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
}
```

I dont understand why it is breaking when I do the Include() statement in my query with the images Model?

Just for reference, this is how I would call to get the first image of a post in my view:

```
@foreach (var gallery in Model)
{
  <img src="@gallery.Images.First().FileName" />
}
```

The query for the for each loop would be the same as I showed

/********* UPDATE ***********/

I initialized my Post model like this:

```
public class Post
{

  public Post()
  {
      Images = new List<Image>();
  }

   public int Id { get; set; }   
   // .....

   public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

}
```

This is how Im trying to load it in right now:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a JSON serialisation problem. I wonder if you're getting a recursive loop problem. Your entity class is slightly wrong though, navigation properties should be `virtual`. For example `public virtual Post Post { get; set; }`

Comment: @DavidG, let me go switch to virtual for Post on image Model, hold on

Comment: No, still same problem

Comment: Is there a way I can just call it like I did in my regular view with gallery.Images.First().Filename but only in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

I had to add this to my Startup.cs class in the public void ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other services here.....

    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
}
```

I got this from this [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577248/web-api-returns-only-one-child-object-from-one-to-many-relationship-using-entity)

I tweaked my model a little to:

```
public class Post
{
      public Post()
      {
          Images = new List<Image>();
      }

      // Other attributes here...

      public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Kept my Image model the same.

And here is what I got for my Images array, which is what I wanted:

[image]

Which then I just appended the image in:

```
success: function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (element) {
                $("#ajaxAppendDIV").append(
                    "<div class='HOME-GALLERY-IMAGE' style='background: url(" + element.images[0].fileName + "); background-position: center; background-size: cover;'></div>" +
```

Answer (score 0):

After our discussion your issue I belive was the ammount of refrence types you had in your object graph that where not being created. I hope this works :). It begins at A post controller where your viewmodel starts to model bind.

```
 public IActionResult Post(PostViewModel pvm)
//objects to save in our db context
Post post = new Post()

//collection objects we will fill the list in below

Tag tag = new Tag();
Image img = new Image();

//these lists will pass the value of pvm.tags List and pvm.Images List
// To our post object

List<Images> ImgHolderList = new List<Images>();
List<Tags> TagHolderList = new List<Tags>();

//bind properties from vm if pvm is valid
if(!ModelState.IsValid){

return BadRequest("error");
}


//... Know add image and tag objects to to our empty holder Collections
ImgHolderList = pvm.Images;//---------> this is where I think the null was comming ftm
TagHolderList = pvm.Tagsl

//bind properties from vm if pvm is valid
if(ImgHolderList == null || TagHolderList == null){

return NoContent();
}

Post.Images = ImageHolderList;//---------> this is where I think the null was comming ftm
Post.Tags = TagHolderList;//---------> this is where I think the null was comming ftm

//---------better to use some design/mapper but for simplicity bind model here
//...add all other properties

post.primitives = pvm.Id;
post.primitives = pvm.Lat

//.......

// know our object graph is full hopefully

   context.Posts.Add(Image1);


                context.SaveChanges();

return Ok;
}




know you want to Get this collection very simple

[Produces("application/json")] //with this your api controller returns json with OK()
    [Route("api/GetAll")]
    public class GetAllController : Controller
    {
    private readonly ApiContext ctx = ApiContext.db; // OR use DI

   // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var x = ctx.Posts.Include(x => x.Images).Include(x => x.Tags)ToList();
            return Ok(x.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Hey Mohamoud Mohamed,  I don;t get what your doing on the top part of the Post class. Should it be something like: `public Post()
        {
            Images = new List<Image>();
        }` Im getting error when copying that top part

Comment: Sorry david your right . I changed it  you need to initialize to do eager loading when you include derp  sorry for the mistake

Comment: I updated my question, look at the bottom of it. Thats what I implemented.

Comment: I updated the model, and reset all migrations, and when I make a new post then try to call it with the `.Include(c => c.Images)` query, the same thing is happening. I'll keep that in my model though.

Comment: I updated. You need to load the collection explicitly if you want to iterate

Comment: Im trying to piece it together, I have `var data = _context.Posts
                .Include(c => c.Category);

            _context.Entry(data).Collection(c => c.// SOmething).Load();` in my query right now

Comment: I made an update to my question in the bottom. IT says "does not contain definition for 'Images' and no extension method for 'Images' accepting a first argument of  type 'IOrderedQuerable<Post>' when I hover over the red line in Visual Studio

Comment: Dont make 2 queries If you want to just load the collection replace data and make it the Entity Post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166136/discussion-between-mohamoud-mohamed-and-david).

Comment: Cant be returning an Ok to a JSON result, and I already tried doing the `.ThenIclude()` statements, didnt work. In my situation, 1 post has Many Images.